# Django Generic Views + JQueryUI Dialog + Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Can anybody provide a quick walk-through?

I have a JQueryUI dialog that is loaded via ajax with a django form.

**jquery**

```
$("#project_add").on(
    "click", {url: "/projects/project_create"}, open_dialog
);

function open_dialog(event) {
    //create the div that will hold the dialog box
    var projectDialog = $('#project_dialog');
    if ($('#project_dialog').length == 0) {
        projectDialog = $('<div id="project_dialog"></div>').appendTo('body');
    }

    // load the passed url into the dialog
    projectDialog.load(event.data.url);

    // create the dialog box and display it
    projectDialog.dialog({
        title: "Create Project",
        position: ['center', 'top'],
        closeOnEscape: true,
        close: function() {projectDialog.dialog("destroy");}
    });
}
```

**django view**

```
class CreateProject(CreateView):
template_name = "projects/project_create.html"
form_class = ProjectCreateForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

**django template**

```
<form action="project_create/" method="post">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="dialog-save">
</form>
```

All I want to do is to keep all the activity in the dialog, ie invalid form entries will have validation messages pop up in the dialog. If the form is valid, I want the dialog to close and return to the page that called the dialog. I messed around with overriding form_valid to try and avoid having to follow a redirect, but to no avail. I end up on a blank page with the url equal to the url passed in the form action attribute. I would like to avoid adding a listener in jquery on the submit button to handle the form validation within js. I have seen a number of posts that suggest doing the validation on the js side, then passing the data into django for saving. I would like to do validation and saving with django.

If I could figure out how to do it, sure I could add a listener to destroy the dialog on successful form submission, but I want to use django for validation and jquery only for presentation. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You must submit form via AJAX and then replace contenets of dialog with HTTP response. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dialog-save', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.prop('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize()
    }).done(function (data) {
        $form.replaceWith(data);
    });
};
```